# How do I do a pattern match for words and characters using regex

Tags: regex

I have incoming payload within which I need to determine if the payload contains any of these words:
`Moscow`  `Russia` and any other words .
In addition also need to check if anywhere in payload any of the following characters are present :
`<` , `>` , `!`

I tried with this basic regex : `\b(?:Moscow|Russia|Elephant|<|>)\b`

while the above regex works against the words it is not case insensitive
and it fails for the specific characters `<`

How do I make the word search case insensitive and make the character search to work ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are only looking for `<>` wi hin word boundaries. Try

```
\b(?:Moscow|Russia|Elephant)\b|[<>]
```

Comment: Your question lacks details, so this is a bit of a shot in the dark. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre]. See also the [`regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) for tag usage guidance and some common beginner questions with their answers.